# Comparing elements at a given index in two arrays in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing

Suppose I have a mongo collection of form

```
test_collection:(
{
  _id:"test_id",
   "name":"abc",
   "array_1":[1,5,3,4],
   "array_2":[3,6,4,5]
},
{
   _id:"test_id_1",
   "name":"efg",
   "array_1":[5,6,7,8],
   "array_2":[8,9,10,11]
},
{
   _id:"test_id_2",
   "name":"mno",
   "array_1":[8,6,7,9],
   "array_2":[1,2,10,11]
})
```

How should I write a query which gives me only those objects from the collection where the value of element at index 0 in array_1 is less than value of element at index 0 in array_2? For example in this case the query should return objects with id **test_id** and **test_id_1**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html#expr) operator:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    "$lt": [
      {$arrayElemAt: ["$array_1",0]},
      {$arrayElemAt: ["$array_2",0]}
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/43KiOMe68_z)